Fuzzy Search with OpenStreetMap
I am trying to implement a restaurant search using OpenStreetMap that corrects typos similarly to Google Search. For example, if a user types 'Tresch,' it should still find the restaurant 'Brasserie Tresznjewski'.
I tried:
Fuse.js
Nominatim OpenStreetMap API
Treshold adjustments
Levenshtein-Algorithmus

The Photon geocoder (which is partly based on Nominatim) has "typo tolerance":

https://photon.komoot.io/
https://github.com/komoot/photon


Great! Works much better!
